# Changing the date format when plotting two columns of a data frames against each other in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

How can I change the date format when plotting two columns of a data frames against each other in pandas?

For example, if I run:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=50)
print('dates: {0}'.format(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates), 1), index=dates, columns=['A'])

print('df: {0}'.format(df))
plt.figure(figsize=(60,15))
df.plot(y='A', use_index=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

I obtain:

[image]

How can I  control the displayed  date format on the xticks?

Am I supposed to cast the dates into a string, as shown below, or is there a neater solution?

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=50)
print('dates: {0}'.format(dates))
# I have just changed the line below to introduce `.astype(str)`:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates), 1), index=dates.astype(str), columns=['A'])

print('df: {0}'.format(df))
plt.figure(figsize=(60,15))
df.plot(y='A', use_index=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.savefig('plot2.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DayLocator` and `MonthLocator` objects from `matplotlib.dates`.  Below I set the major ticks as the first of each month, the minor ticks as the 11th and 21st of each month, and formatted the dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(df)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(DayLocator([11,21]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels(which='both'), rotation=70)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]